# php gd GRAYSCALE

Tags: php, gd, php-gd

i have a code in php with the GD library and it gives error

here is the code :

```
<?php
    header('content-type: image/png');
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('a.png');
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

and here is the error :

> the image localhost/image/gdimg.php cannot displayed because it contains errors

what is wrong here?

Comment: Which browser are you using? What does happen if you save the image to disk and open it with an image viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove line

```
header('content-type: image/png');
```

and you will see php error.

Comment: This code works great for me.. maybe  a.png is damaged. Try with other image.